# simpler form of std::unordered_map::insert?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Is there an easier way to check whether an `std::unordered_map::insert` call succeeded than writing this mammoth block of code?

```
std::pair< T1, T2 > pair(val1, val2);
std::pair< std::unordered_map< T1, T2 >::const_iterator, bool> ret =
 _tileTypes.insert(pair);
if(!ret.second) {
    // insert did not succeed
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about just:

```
if(!_tileTypes.insert(std::make_pair(val1, vla2)).second) {
    // insert did not succeed
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
if (!_tileTypes.insert(pair).second)
```

?

Alternatively, typedefs can be useful to tidy this sort of thing up.

Also, if you're using C++11, then you can use the `auto` keyword to infer the type:

```
auto ret = _tileTypes.insert(pair);
```

Comment: And if you need access to `.first` after checking `.second`, you can use `auto` to simplify the long return value type.